# Permanent document identifier requirement for DBLP indexing?

Tags: conference, arxiv, doi, indexing

First of all we are holding a conference which is the 12th year of this conference. All english papers of this conference from the 7th year are indexed in IEEE, however for the first 6 years there exist no document identifier over internet. We would like to index this year's conference papers in DBLP in addition to IEEE. I have read [this page](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/faq/What+are+the+criteria+for+dblp+to+index+a+journal+or+conference.html) about the requirements to index proceedings of conferences in DBLP.
So there are my questions:

1. Since there are no permanent identifers for the first 6 years of this conference is it possible to index papers from the 7th year up to now in DBLP or it should be a complete collection of all 12 years of conference?
2. In the DBLP help page, it's noted that

> All contributions should be registered for permanent document
>   identifiers, such as DOI.

May an Arxiv identifier be accepted as a **permanent document identifier** for indexing in DBLP?

Any answer would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your best bet is to ask the DBLP administrators directly; they are remarkably responsive, in my experience.  (DBLP does index arXiv preprints.)

Comment: JeffE is correct, you should contact dblp@dagstuhl.de and state your case. As a general guideline, DOI is a best-practice example of a persistent identifier. In fact, more that 80% of the documents in dblp do carry a DOI, including even many historic papers. There are other handle systems or even just well-structured URL schemes of digital libraries that are accepted by dblp as well, but assigning DOIs is currently the way to go if you want your publications to be found in years from now.

Comment: @MRA Can you please turn your comment into an answer, so that I can vote for it?

Comment: There is no reason that DOIs cannot be issued to past issues of the conference proceedings. They will have to be re-indexed of course, so that they can pick up the change in metadata.